# Python: Find the sum of alternate elements in a matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I need to find the sum of elements in alternate position. What I tried is below which is working only for the given order(2x3) only. Also how can I write a generalize function SumPos(matrix,order) to take the matrix from user input in main and do the operation in the function? For simplicity it may be a square matrix.

```
numbers= [[1,4,7,6],[8,5,1,11]]

evensum = 0 #sum for even numbers

oddsum = 0 #sum for odd numbers

for i in range(len(numbers)): 

  for j in range(len(numbers[i])): #loop visit value in matrix 

    if(j%2==0): #if the number is even position

        print('even=',numbers[i][j])  
        evensum +=numbers[i][j]

    else:
      print('odd=',numbers[i][j])  
      oddsum+=numbers[i][j]
  
#print output

print('Evensum=',evensum)

print('Oddsum=',oddsum)
```

Please help

Comment: What do you mean by working only for given dimension ?

Comment: @rtm The only possibility is to set the traversal indexes as dimensions

Comment: Changed in OP with proper terminology.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `input()` in which the user inputs a discrete value such as `0 or 1` to select the dimension:

```
numbers= [[1,4,7,6],[8,5,1,11]]

evensum = 0
oddsum = 0
dim = int(input("Enter dimension 0/1 vertical/horizontal:\n"))

for i in range(len(numbers)):
    for j in range(len(numbers[i])):
        if dim==0:
            if(j%2==0):  
                evensum +=numbers[i][j]
            else:
              oddsum+=numbers[i][j]
        elif dim==1:
            if(i%2==0):  
                evensum +=numbers[i][j]
            else:
              oddsum+=numbers[i][j]
print(evensum, oddsum)
```

> > Output

```
Enter dimension 0/1 horizontal/vertical:
0
17 26
```

Comment: If the dimension  is 2x3 like,  numbers= [[1,4,7],[8,5,1]] then the evensum=1+7+5=13 and oddsum=4+8+1=13 considering the first position is 0 which is even. But the answer is deferring.